# Jquery, resize image by width keeping constant height

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I go about resizing/cropping an image so the height is constant but its width gets smaller as the page is resized?

The same effect as you can see in the carousel here:

http://dai.com/

Thanks,

Comment: Well, I've no idea how it is done without some kind of ration. Hence the question, i just need a hint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you looked at the website image closely? Because it's not resizing! It's just centered in the middle of the `img` element as an `background` property. When you change the width of the screen you will see that the image center is adjusted..

It's pretty simple to accomplish this effect by using only the `background` property:

`background: url("img path") 50% 0 no-repeat;`

The background image will get the height of the element.

Example: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4Uv7y/1/)

Answer (score 0):

you should bind a function to the "resize" event, 
 and give the image max-width and max-height instead of height and width,

```
 function imageresize() {  
 if (($(window).width()) < '800'){  
 $('#img').css('max-width',$(window).width());  
 } else {  
 $('#img').css('max-width','');  
 }  
 }  

 imageresize();

 $(window).resize(function(){
 imageresize();  
 });
```

I attached a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gGBRF/

Answer (score 0):

As @Sven said, it's not being re-sized it's just centered and re-sizing the browser making it looks like it's an overflow from both sides.